# Spell letter by letter

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm building an Android app that will get user input by using **voice to Text**.

The user is going to enter codes just like 'AA001', 'BC022', 'AD011' and so on. I am already able to open the voice Recognition Activity and get user input from it (snippet below, from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/)), but it returns words.

I need a way to set it up in order to get just the letters and numbers the user had really entered.

```
private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean taking a little break after spelling each letter? Yes I did. Speaking very softly, I was able to get 'a 1001' when trying to say 'AA001'. But it's not still what I need.

Comment: Sorry, I read that wrong, I thought it was text-to-speech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do it with Google engine. You can do it with other engines like [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid). There you can specify a grammar to recognize only letters and digits, the grammar should look like this:

```
#JSGF V1.0;
grammar alphadigits;
public <letters> = (one | two | three | four | ... | a. | b. | c. | d. ... | z.)*;
```

Such grammar will return you only digits with higher accuracy than Google native API.

For better recognition accuracy it is also recommended to add letter combinations into the grammar instead of letter. For example if you want "aa", then add "aa" to the grammar. Letters are too short to be recognized reliably.

Comment: I'm going to study this engine and try it next week. Results will be shared here. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Ok, let me know if there are issues.

Comment: Just testing the example, it seems to be a lot closer to what I'm needing. Thanks !

Comment: I really liked this engine, but ended up using Google's default with keywords, like 'A'='apple'. The decision was taken cause of lack of time, and the app is required to run in Brazilian Portuguese, wich is not easy to get working properly with these (http://www.laps.ufpa.br/falabrasil/downloads.php) resources. But i think that would be the right choice if I would have time to learn how to get this engine working properly and accomplish the project's deadline.

Comment: As asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069363/sphinx-to-recognize-alphabet-accuracy-is-very-low, CMUSphinx does a not-good-enough job at letters/digits recognition. I tried to implement it myself and ended up throwing the branch :(

Comment: I also attempted this for spelling alphanumeric, modifying the dictionary/grammar and got some bezerk results https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178110
Can any of you recommend a better tool for the task?